# Android onActivityResult is not getting called when i edit an excel file using ACTION_EDIT intent.

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

i want to open a excel file when a user selects it from listview. and i want to know whether the opened file is edited or not . when ever user edits a file i want to upload that file to server how can i do that thing. i tried with the following code but the "onactivityresult" method is not getting called .

**Code:**

**Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.m.media"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"
        />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />




        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <!-- <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" /> -->
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />


    </intent-filter>
</activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MyActivity:**

```
    listviewv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {

                    String item=filenames.get(position);
                    String ext = item.substring(item.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
                    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
                    File videoFile2Play = new File(filepath.get(position));
                    Intent i = new Intent();

                    i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                    i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(videoFile2Play), type);
                    i.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
                    startActivityForResult(i, EDIT_CONTACT_RESULT);
                   // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), filepath.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });


 @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          if (requestCode == EDIT_CONTACT_RESULT) {
                // Make sure the request was successful
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "edited", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

     }
     }
```

but the onactivityresult method is not getting called when i save the edit changes. how can i get notified when an edit occurred in opened file. please help me in solving this problem.

i am using the android vesion-4.0.3.

Comment: What is the value of constant `EDIT_CONTACT_RESULT`?

Comment: How do you know that `onActivityResult()` is not called? You only check if `resultCode == RESULT_OK` and then generate a `Toast` (which, by the way, is not a reliable way to debug), but `resultCode` could also be `RESULT_CANCELED`, especially if the activity you are launching is running in another task.

Comment: yes i am getting the resultCode as RESULT_CANCELED. how can i detect whether the file has been modified or not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you are getting `onActivityResult()` called with `RESULT_CANCELED`, I'm assuming that whatever activity is launched when you invoke the EDIT action is running in another task. In this case you cannot rely on getting a useful result back from `startActivityOnResult()`.

To see if the file has been modified, you probably need to use a different approach. Try implementing a `FileObserver` to watch the file that you are editing and listen for the `MODIFY` event.

Comment: but if i use a fileobserver it is calling create,modified,deleted,close_write,and close_nowrite events multiple times  when i modified the file. so i am not able identify whether the file should be uploaded to server or not. i want to make dropbox kind of application if you know any sample projects or any releated information please kindly post the links below.

Comment: You could try just using `lastModified()` method on the `File` object to determine if the file has been changed since the last update.